# Magento2 : different templates for multistore, how?

Tags: magento2, template, multistore

On magento1, I could achieve this by

1, I had my theme folder "**mydesign**" under frontend/default

2, Another store's folder was also added under frontend/default as "**mydesign-en**"

3, "**mydesign-en**" had a template folder under it and there I could have different template files than main store.

4, I applied on the backend configuration under design section "theme setting", for **default and skin "mydesign"** and **for template "mydesign-en"**.

However, I see the design configuration is different on the backend of Magento2.

At the moment I have **mytheme/mydesign** under `app/design/frontend`.
Do I have to create **another child theme as mytheme/mydesign-en** to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should create a new theme under `app/design/frontend/mytheme`. Its parent is your current custom theme. For example:

- You create Theme A1 for store A
- And then create Theme B1 for store B. Its parent theme is Theme A1.

Now, in Theme B1, you can create the new layout and style for catalog product page on store B:

*app/design/frontend/mytheme/B1/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml*

Comment: I have app/design/frontend/mytheme and for store A theme A1 and for store B  themeB1. But it is not working. There is no setting on the backend needed?

Comment: Which is your Magento version?

Comment: latest version, 2.1.4

Comment: For 2.1.4, go to **CONTENT > Configuration** and apply the custom theme.

Comment: somehow I thought I didn't need to create another custom theme structure (eg. theme.xml, registration.php etc). I created B1theme as same structure as A1 theme then I could apply in the backend. However, it is not the design of A1 as parent, such as CSS setting.

Comment: @rtk0407 At least, we must have `theme.xml`, `registration.php ` for the new custom theme.

Comment: I have them, but CSS settings of A1 is not visible in B1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53389/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-rtk0407).

Comment: Seem that you didn't create the `web` folder and didn't have any asset under this folder. You should put some assets under `web` folder.

Comment: I  created freshly another custom theme, went through the step Khoa instructed and somehow this time it worked!